# Spark Scala joining the same data frame and removing bi-directional relationships

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I recently started developing on Spark Scala, and I encountered a problem in trying to join 2 DataFrames of the same table were I have:

DataFrame A:

```
Column Names:{AID, AName} 
Data:{1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d}
```

and

DataFrame B:

```
Column Names {BID, AID, BName}
Data: {AB232:1:"Mark", AC32D:1:"Sarah", D2123:1:"John", S23DS:2:"Matthew"}
```

I need to get all those names which are connected with each other in this case I need to get:

```
"Mark" - "Sarah" , "Mark" - "John", "Sarah"- "John"
```

Instead when I try to join DataFrame B (Here B1 and B2 is an instance of B):

```scala
B1.joinWith(B2, B1("AID")  === B2("AID) && B1("BID") =!= B2("BID") );
```

After this join I select the resulting table to get the BName from both dataframes.

The result I get is:

```
"Mark" - "Sarah" ,"Sarah"- "Mark", "Mark" - "John", "John" - "Mark", "Sarah"- "John", "John"- "Sarah".
```

Is there a way were I can check if the data already exists in both columns so that I can avoid bi-directional relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<` instead of `=!=` to compare `BID`, so that you only match records where `B2.BID` is greater then `B1.BID`, hence only one "instance" of each match is joined:

```
B1.joinWith(B2, B1("AID")  === B2("AID") && B1("BID") < B2("BID")).show()
// +---------------+---------------+
// |_1             |_2             |
// +---------------+---------------+
// |[AB232,1,Mark] |[D2123,1,John] |
// |[AB232,1,Mark] |[AC32D,1,Sarah]|
// |[AC32D,1,Sarah]|[D2123,1,John] |
// +---------------+---------------+
```

**EDIT** of course you can also leave your join as-is, and filter afterwords:

```
B1.joinWith(B2, B1("AID") === B2("AID") && B1("BID") =!= B2("BID"))
  .filter($"_1.BID" < $"_2.BID")
```

As [@T. Gaweda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811800/t-gaw%C4%99da) pointed out, it might be faster - feel free to try both on your actual data and see :)

Comment: Isn't it better to do filter after joining? In your current approach, the join will use cross join with filtering. When you join only with `===`, then sort-merge join will be used

Comment: Good point - although I'm not sure that's true, I think Catalyst might be able to do that optimization for me. Using these small datasets and Spark 2.0.1 I see identical physical plans for both implementations.

Comment: Ok, maybe it was optimized ;) Some time ago I read that only `===` can be optimized, maybe there was some changes :)

Comment: Anyway - edited the answer to include this - thanks!

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick reply. That worked for my sample dataset, but wouldn't it fail if there is a BID greater then the one you are comparing resulting in bi-directional relationships?

Comment: I'm not following - can you give an example? For every two records with matching `AID`, one record's `BID` is necessarily larger then the other one's, unless they are equal...

Comment: You are right sorry for my misunderstanding. Marking it as an answer- Thanks!